# Why does Mosquitto not apply access lists correctly?

Tags: mosquitto

I tried to apply an access list to a user, but [Mosquitto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker#List_of_message_broker_software) always takes the highest access level and apply it.

I tried to apply this:

```
user roger
topic readwrite device/1/#
topic read device/1/name/
```

I also tried:

```
user roger
topic read device/1/name/
topic readwrite device/1/#
```

In both cases it allows read/write to the topic:

```
device/1/name/
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The man page that covers the ACL format doesn't make any comment on the behaviour of overlapping topic patterns, so this may just be undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

device/1/name/ is part of this "topic readwrite device/1/#" 
you cant enable access to all subtopics and after that disabling one sub topic is not possible :"topic read device/1/name/"

you can try allow one level subtopic to readwrite access

"topic readwrite device/1/+" "topic read device/1/name/subtopic".

you can write and read

- "device/1/subtopic"
- "device/1/anothertopic"
- "device/1/name"

.

but you can only read

- "device/1/name/subtopic"